# How to replace a string with dashes or question marks?

Tags: java, string

So I'm in the process of making a hangman game where a user enters in a word and then the word is displayed but disguised in question marks. Every time the user enters in a word correctly, the letter appears in place of the question mark. I have all the code necessary for the guessing and etc, I just need someones help with disguising the word entered in by the user in question marks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Bob = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> alphabet = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"));//i looked this part up Mr. A, I didn't know how to directly set values in an arraylist
    int guesses = 6;//wrong guesses

    System.out.println("Hello! Please enter in your word for the game. Only one word is allowed!");
    String word = Bob.next();
    int lettersInWord = word.length();//so you know if you've solved the word or not

    while(guesses > 0 && lettersInWord > 0){ //not or because you'll end up getting a negative 1
        System.out.println("What is your guess? One letter at a time please or you'll mess up my game.");
        String guess = Bob.next();
        guess.toLowerCase(); //i populated the arraylist with only lowercase letters so it has to be this way
        while(!alphabet.contains(guess)){ //since I remove letters from the arraylist, this is like the default to make sure a guess doesn't happen twice
            System.out.println("You already guessed this letter, or this is not a letter");
            guess = Bob.next();//just lets user make another guess
        }
        alphabet.remove(guess);//takes letter out of alphabet so no redoes happen
        if(word.contains(guess)){
            System.out.println("Yeauhhhhh, thats right! You guessed " + guess);
            lettersInWord--;//makes the word size smaller
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nahhhhh, that's wrong! You guessed " + guess + " and it is not in the word");
            guesses--;//takes a guess away
        }

        System.out.println("You have " + guesses + " wrong guesses left"); //displays at the end of the iteration
    }
    if(guesses == 0){//this comes up when you lose
        System.out.println("You have lost, the word was "+ word);
    } else {//this comes up when you've guessed the word, if its not one its the other!!!
        System.out.println("You have won! the word was  "+ word  + "good job dude. Please see\n"
                + "Mr. A for a free piece of cake and a 100 on your final.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we can assist you better. None of us here have the ability of guessing what your code looks like.

Comment: You need to be more precise on what kind of help you expect from us. Post some examples of input, expected results, and what wrong is happening with your code when you try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You create a separate String of question marks the same length as your word.

```
String marks = "";
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    marks += "?";
}
```

When a letter is guessed correctly, you replace a question mark with the letter.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but once the string marks has been declared as all question marks, how would I replace a question mark with a character in the correct position?

Comment: @mj_doo You can't. Strings are immutable so you need to create new string with different set of question mark. If I ware you I would probably start with `char[]` array which can store `?` at start and when I need a string I would call `new String(myCharArray)`.

Comment: @Pshemo has a better idea.  You can also recreate the marks String after each guess by saving and using the letters that you remove from the alphabet list.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making a simple example for you

```
   public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String word = "Hello";
        String unCapWord = word.toLowerCase();
        int guesses = word.length();
        int count = 0;
        char usedLetters[] = new char[26];
        String testWin;


        char[] guessBox = new char[word.length()];
        for (int i =0; i < word.length(); i++)
            guessBox[i] = '?';
        Scanner bob = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (count < guesses) {
            char guess = bob.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            String checkIfCharUsed = new String(usedLetters);
            if (checkIfCharUsed.contains(guess+"")) {
                System.out.println("Already used this char, try another!");
                continue;
            }
            for (int i =0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if (unCapWord.charAt(i) == guess)
                    guessBox[i] = guess;

            }
            testWin = new String(guessBox);
            if (testWin.equals(unCapWord)) {
                System.out.println("You got it!");
                return;
            }
            usedLetters[count] = guess;
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("You lost!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quick and dirty, but will display dashes for each letter in the word being guessed.  As you guess correct letters, the dashes will be replaced with the guessed letter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner Bob = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> alphabet = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"));//i looked this part up Mr. A, I didn't know how to directly set values in an arraylist
    int guesses = 6;//wrong guesses

    System.out.println("Hello! Please enter in your word for the game. Only one word is allowed!");
    String word = Bob.next();
    int lettersInWord = word.length();//so you know if you've solved the word or not
    String[] lettersOfWord = new String[lettersInWord];
    // Replace "-" with "?" if you want to use question marks
    Arrays.fill(lettersOfWord, "-");

    clearScreen();
    String guess = "";
    int lettersCorrect = -1;
    while (guesses > 0 && lettersInWord > 0) { //not or because you'll end up getting a negative 1
        if (lettersCorrect > 0) {
            System.out.println(String.format("There %s %d %s", 
                    lettersCorrect > 1 ? "are" : "is", lettersCorrect, guess));

            lettersCorrect = 0;
        } else if (lettersCorrect == 0) {
            System.out.println("Nahhhhh, that's wrong! You guessed " + guess + " and it is not in the word");
        }
        System.out.println(String.join("", lettersOfWord));
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("You have " + guesses + " wrong guesses left"); //displays at the end of the iteration
        System.out.println("What is your guess? One letter at a time please or you'll mess up my game.");
        guess = Bob.next().toLowerCase();

        while (!alphabet.contains(guess)) { //since I remove letters from the arraylist, this is like the default to make sure a guess doesn't happen twice
            System.out.println("You already guessed this letter, or this is not a letter");
            guess = Bob.next();//just lets user make another guess
        }
        alphabet.remove(guess);//takes letter out of alphabet so no redoes happen
        if (word.contains(guess)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if (guess.equals(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)))) {
                    lettersOfWord[i] = guess;
                    lettersInWord--;
                    lettersCorrect++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            guesses--;//takes a guess away
        }

        clearScreen();
    }
    if (guesses == 0) {//this comes up when you lose
        System.out.println("You have lost, the word was " + word);
    } else {//this comes up when you've guessed the word, if its not one its the other!!!
        System.out.println("You have won! the word was " + word + " good job dude. Please see\n"
                + "Mr. A for a free piece of cake and a 100 on your final.");
    }
}

// Simulate a clear screen
private static void clearScreen() {
    for(int clear = 0; clear < 1000; clear++) {
       System.out.println("\b") ;
    }
}
```